# NavigationView bar material invisible on iOS 15

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

On iOS 15, an app with a `NavigationView` with `.inline` mode no longer shows the blurry material color you would see for the navigation bar.

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red.ignoresSafeArea()
                
                Text("Content")
            }
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comparison:

| iOS 14.4 | iOS 15 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: iOS 14.4 result] | [image: iOS 15 result] |

How can I fix this to keep the iOS 14 behaviour?

Comment: I think it's a new design thing. It's the same with `TabView` - when the background doesn't scroll, there is no line. If you put the `ZStack` in a `ScrollView` you get the old behavior back, kind of.

Comment: @aheze I heard something on Twitter that this is part of the "What's new in UIKit" so I may have a watch of that WWDC session and then change the behaviour with [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect)... but I wish there is a nicer solution.

Comment: @workingdog Unfortunately didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not perfect, there is a way to solve this by using [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect).

It still has a problem that for the first render the change has not had an effect yet.

The solution I found was partially discovered from [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/682420?answerId=678641022#678641022).

With Introspect, I added the following code:

```
NavigationView {
    /* ... */
}
.introspectNavigationController { navController in
    navController.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navController.navigationBar.standardAppearance
    navController.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}
```

It now works, but would be nicer if there was a 100% SwiftUI solution.

Comment: This works well for me when the navigation bar is always inline, but on pages where there's a large nav title it shows the gray background and line at the bottom of the title - any idea how you could restore the normal transparent appearance for the large title?

Comment: @sia I'm not sure, I gave up with this and just accepted the change. However if you search around for a UIKit solution, then that's what you need. The single-frame flash was a deal-breaker for me, which is why I decided not to use this code.

Answer (score 0):

one workaround is this:

```
 struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                // choose your color here
                Color(red: 1, green: 0.8, blue: 0.8).ignoresSafeArea()
                Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
                Text("Content")
            }.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```